# Nested Loops Multiple Entries

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I ran into another problem. I'm trying to figure out how to only have 1 record set of the `newResult` variable instead of it displaying many times?

qrykeylist is from the database.
and newArray is not from database but constructed from the array.

I needed to loop over both in order to get all the results. I managed to get them how I wanted but I cannot figure out how to make it only show 1 record result set from both of the looped over results from both the query and array.

I googled around and some have told me when having nested loops put both into an array of structures but how can I do that if both of these needs to be looped over? In addition, I cannot write this outside of inner loop because I need to use BOTH variables to output the results.

Here is my code:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(newArray)#">
        <cfloop query="qrykeylist">
            <strong><br>#ITEM[i]#</strong>
            <cfset newResult = SHOULDBE - newArray[i]>
                <cfif newArray[i] GT SHOULDBE>
                    <br>Missing Keys #newResult#
                    <cfelseif newArray[i] LT SHOULDBE>
                    <br>Extra Keys #newResult#
                    <cfelseif newArray[i] EQ SHOULDBE>
                    <br>No Missing Keys
                </cfif> 
                <cfbreak>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
```

Here is the results of the image the ones that arent in boxes are being duplicated most likely by the loop?

[image]

Comment: Could you do a dump of `qrykeylist` and a dump of `newArray` ?

Comment: Did it. First screenshot is qrykeylist and second one is newarray right below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a comment, but it way too long. It looks like you have

```
<cfoutput query="qrykeylist">
   <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(newArray)#">
      <cfloop query="qrykeylist">
```

This is nested 3 levels deep. I don't think you want loop over `qrykeylist` twice.

**On a different note

```
<cfif #newArray[i]# GT #SHOULDBE#>
```

could be written as:

```
<cfif newArray[i] GT SHOULDBE>
```

You only wrap variables in ## when displaying the values.

Comment: I re-submitted screenshot. I'm trying to get "2" side by side with "garage remote", "1" with "guest door key", "0" with "Housekeeping Door Key" and so on I feel im close but I'm missing something

Comment: I figured it out. Posted my new code. had to add `#ITEM[I]#`

Comment: You should write that up as the answer